# ruby で Value Object を効率的に記述したい

Tags: ruby

ruby で開発をしています。プログラムを開発していると、多種多様な Value Object を定義することに (定義したく) なりますが、その手順が、以下に示す通り同じようなことの繰り返しなので、どうにか効率化できないかと考えています。

具体例 Value Object クラス

```
class Person
  attr_reader :name, :age
  def initialize(name, age)
    @name = name
    @age = age
  end

  def ==(other)
    name == other.name &&
      age == other.age
  end
end
```

これは、２つのフィールドを持つクラスなので、まだシンプルですが、フィールド数が増えてくると、特にフィールド変更のプログラム修正を行う場合などに苦痛です。

質問:

- ruby において value object を効率よく記述するための手法・ライブラリなどはありますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Structクラス](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/class/Struct.html)を使う方法はどうでしょうか？

```
Person = Struct.new(:name, :age) do
  def initialize(*args)
    super
    freeze
  end
end

taro = Person.new('太郎', 18)
hanako = Person.new('花子', 18)
taro_adult = Person.new('太郎', 36)
taro_clone = Person.new('太郎', 18)

puts taro
puts taro == hanako
puts taro == taro_adult
puts taro == taro_clone

taro.age = 19 # => Error
```

単に`Struct.new`でクラスを作成した場合はmutableなオブジェクトになってしまいますので、`initialize`を上書き定義して`freeze`しておく必要があります。

他にもいくつかgemがあるようですので、そちらを使うという手もあります。

- [value](https://rubygems.org/gems/value)
- [value_object](https://rubygems.org/gems/value_object)
- [value-object](https://rubygems.org/gems/value-object)
- [value_struct](https://rubygems.org/gems/value_struct)